# Can I do the server rendering with data in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on react recently. I am using the server rendering with react-router, but it can only render the HTML from react components, and I need to get the initial data via ajax in `componentDidMount()`.

The problem is for some pages/components, they need the initial data to render. So if users visit such a page directly(by typing url or refresh), the page broken, because the server cannot render it without initial data.

I'm thinking can I get the data from database and insert it to template when rendering in server? Just like what classic front-end template or PHP does.

If no way, what's the best practice for rendering first-page data?

Now my server code is like:

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log('GET ADMIN');
  match({
    routes: appRoutes,
    location: req.originalUrl
  }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500)
        .send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302)
        .redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var content = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps}/>);
      var html = swig.renderFile('src/client/admin.html', {
        content: content
      });
      res.status(200)
        .send(html);
    } else {
      res.status(404)
        .send('Not found');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's called isomorphic or universal rendering, I made a simplistic example without flux here - https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/. I recommend you google that as there are a lot of varying approaches. It's not the simplest subject matter.

Comment: @DominicTobias Thx. I have read some tutorials about isomorphic app. What I learned is just how to render the HTML without data. Can you check the code I just edited to the post? So you mean I do can rendering the page with real-time data(get from database)? That's a good news. I am gonna read your link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in GitHub: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1969#issuecomment-140988110

This method insert all data you need into the HTML template when rendering in server and get the data in front-end as `context`. All component can get the data via `context`.

I use a `<DataWrapper>` component to wrap the original root app component. On the server side when rendering:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data); // data is an object
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<DataWrapper data={data}><RoutingContext {...renderProps}/></DataWrapper>)
```

and the `<DataWrapper>` is something like:

```
import React from 'react';

class DataWrapper extends React.Component {

    getChildContext () {

        return {
            data: this.props.data
        };
    }

    render () {

        return this.props.children;
    }
}

DataWrapper.childContextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default DataWrapper;
```

on the client side:

```
var data    = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML),
    history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<DataWrapper data={ data }><Router history={ history }>{ routes }</Router></DataWrapper>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

get the data via context in components:

```
class someComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor (props, context) {

        super(props, context);
        this.state = context.data.someData;
    }
}

someComponent.contextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default someComponent;
```

it works well

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using an AJAX call for the initialisation is that it forces you to render first without the data and then to re-render once the data arrives.

A better way is to include the data in the page so it's there for your initial render. e.g.

```
<script>
    var __INITIAL_DATA__ = { /* etc */ }
</script>
```

Yeah globals are ugly. But necessary in this instance. And you only use it once to initialise your React component. (Or your store if you're using Flux.)

And yes indeed, in isomorphic/universal apps you use the same data in your server side code. Just like in PHP and other server side languages. Only your server side code won't be pulling from a global variable. The data should be passed directly into the React component that you're mounting.